# Postgres, function "jsonb_extract_path_text" gives no result

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I want to use function "jsonb_extract_path_text", but it gives no result.
I started with Hibernate and CriteriaBuilder, but eventually I simplified my situation.

Now I have several lines in pgAdmin Query Tool (also tested in psql console) and examples from the PostgreSQL Documentation.

First statement with the operator works fine:

```
SELECT '{"a": {"b":{"c": "foo"}}}'::jsonb#>>'{a,b}';
```

and it gives me

```
{"c": "foo"}
```

When I try to use the appropriate function and pass both operands as an arguments:

```
SELECT jsonb_extract_path_text('{"a": {"b":{"c": "foo"}}}'::jsonb , '{a,b}');
```

it gives me NULL.

I also tried to define path using the array constructor:

```
SELECT jsonb_extract_path_text('{"a": {"b":{"c": "foo"}}}'::jsonb , ARRAY['a','b']);
```

and it gives me an error message:

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_extract_path_text(jsonb, text[]) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What's wrong with these statements?
My Postgres version is 9.6.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT jsonb_extract_path_text('{"a": {"b":{"c": "foo"}}}'::jsonb , 'a','b');
```

Comment: 1) it's json array inside 2) I need like query. Will it work?